# Career advice : changing gears from devops to coding

Tags: career-development

I have two decades of working with all aspects around devops, before it was called that! I have written and reviewed a lot of code and helped design and deploy a number of enterprise projects and standalone tools. Does the fact that I have never explicitly been in a developer role or on a dev team make it impossible for me to get a formal coding role?

I find the process to be more fulfilling and the pay looks better on the higher end of the ladder, but starting at the bottom isn't ideal for a number of reasons and going for a more fitting role may be problematic because of no explicit coding experience.

I'm considering stuff I know best - C, C++/RogueWave/boost, SQL, Java, assembly, FIX protocol, Perl, some Python and so on.

Comment: It may be the case that you could back up your skills with some credentials. You might want to take courses in the languages used by the type of organizations you want to work for. That will give you some credentials to go with your experience and this will make you look better on paper. There are a very large number of people that have already done what you are trying to do. I've been a software engineer for 30+ years and I work with brilliant people that do not have college degrees who build large-scale software systems and products. Go for it.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the fact that I have never explicitly been in a developer role or
> on a dev team make it impossible for me to get a formal coding role?

No.

You just have to convince the hiring manager that you are capable of filling the role.

> I find the process to be more fulfilling and the pay looks better on
> the higher end of the ladder, but starting at the bottom isn't ideal
> for a number of reasons

Certainly starting at the bottom is never ideal.

It's likely that you'll need to start somewhere close to the bottom.

Comment: I find that when someone with a decade+ of senior, team lead hands-on roles starts even considering a low to mid level position, recruiters and hiring managers get suspucious

Answer (score 0):

> I'm considering stuff I know best - C, C++/RogueWave/boost, SQL, Java, assembly, FIX protocol, Perl, some Python and so on.

Narrow things down to a more concise technology stack.  It's great to know a lot of things, but in a real development situation a manager needs to hire someone with *expertise* and who can hit the ground running.  C, C++, assembly development jobs are their own classification - low level languages.  Java, Perl, Python are a second classification - high level languages.  With SQL, you need to be more concise (Oracle?  MSSQL?  MySQL?  Something else?) because the variants are not the same and you can't magically replace experience on one of these with experience on the other.

I'm also not seeing any front end development (mobile, console, web, desktop, or pure SOAP/REST as an alternative) whereas these are also separate but important classifications.

Even with the time under your belt as you described, you'll have much better chances as a *specialist* than as a *generalist*.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. You are correct in that I don't have front end experience of any consequence, besides some work with PHP/Laravel, raw Qt and some ancient Delphi/Lazarus. Most of my work was in back-end, for financial industry, telecoms (billing and routing) and some full text search/indexing. Majority of my commercial work was interacting with other people's code at every level from specs and design all the way to production support. So I had to maintain superficial knowledge of _all_ the stuff (vs thorough knowledge of fewer important things)